# Do FAA regulations apply indoors?

Tags: regulations, faa

If I fly my drone around inside my house, do FAA regulations apply? (Ignore the fact that they will almost certainly not care.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, FAA Rules do not include indoor spaces.  See this link for clarity:  https://www.faa.gov/faq?combine&field_faq_category_target_id=1491&page=1